# How to recursively add object key-value pairs to an array of objects with child arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, javascript-objects

I'm still learning the ropes of recursion, and I would like to add 'isChecked: false' to every object in this nested tree of arrays.

```
const nestedMap = (arr) => {
  const result = arr.map(row => {
    if (row.children.length) {
      const children = row.children.map(child => {
        return { ...child, isChecked: false };
      });
      return { ...row, isChecked: false, children };
    } else {
      return { ...row, isChecked: false };
    }
  });
  return result[0].children[0]
}

nestedMap([{title: 'page1', children: [{title: 'page2', children: [{title: 'page4'}]}, {title: 'page3'}]}, {title: 'page5', children: []}])
```

Here's my result - as you can see I'm successfully updating the first set of children, but not the rest.

```
{ title: 'page2',
  children: [ { title: 'page4' } ],
  isChecked: false }
```

I know I'm supposed to call the function somewhere inside itself, but I'm an idiot. As always, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if-statement `if (row.children.length) {` checks if `row.children` is an array with length > 0, so here's where you'd want to call `nestedMap` again.

Try something like this:

```js
const nestedMap = (arr) => {
  const result = arr.map(row => {
    // check if row.children exists AND if its length exists / is greater than 0
    if (row.children && row.children.length) {
      const children = nestedMap(row.children);
      return { ...row, isChecked: false, children };
    } else {
      return { ...row, isChecked: false };
    }
  });
  // Note: You should probably return the entire result here, not result[0].children[0]
  return result;
}

let output = nestedMap([{title: 'page1', children: [{title: 'page2', children: [{title: 'page4'}]}, {title: 'page3'}]}, {title: 'page5', children: []}])

console.log(output)
```

Notice I made 3 changes:

1. `if (row.children && row.children.length) {`

   - I added the check to make sure `row.children` exists, before checking `row.children.length`
2. `const children = nestedMap(row.children);`

   - This is where we do the recursion :)
3. `return result;`

   - This will return the entire result (the original nested array of objects, with `isChecked: false` in every object).
   - Note: I'm not sure why you ended your function with `result[0].children[0]`, which will only return the original array's first item's first child?

Comment: Ah, I returned that result because I was messing about with the function on repl and I couldn't see the contents of the nested arrays. Don't worry I haven't gone bonkers yet!  

But thank you ever so much, particularly for your explanation of the changes you made. It really helps :). Hopefully one day it'll click.

Comment: Me again! Any idea why I might be getting undefined in the nested arrays?

Comment: @ZaladiN Glad I could help! And Hmm, where in the nested array are you getting `undefined`?

Comment: Hmm, so when I console.log your `output` variable, it's fine e.g. `output[0].children`. But if I console.log the result variable, I get `undefined` e.g. `result[0].children`.

Comment: Hey @ZaladiN if you put your `console.log(result[0].children)` above `return result;`, I would expect you to get `undefined` sometimes - since `nestedMap` is run multiple times, and sometimes the parameter `arr` has a first element `[0]` which doesn't have a `children` property

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to write a more generic `nestedMap` implementation, and then pass it a function which adds your property.  Here's how I might write it:

```js
const nestedMap = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .map (({children, ...rest}) => fn ({
    ... rest,
    ... (children ? {children: nestedMap (fn) (children)} : {})
  }))

const addProp = (key, val) => (obj) => 
  ({... obj, [key]: val})

const pages = [{title: 'page1', children: [{title: 'page2', children: [{title: 'page4'}]}, {title: 'page3'}]}, {title: 'page5', children: []}]

console .log (
  nestedMap (addProp ('checked', false)) (pages)
)
```

This version does not mutate our original, but creates a new array full of new objects.  (It does not do a full clone; other properties of our nodes may be shared by reference.)

**`addProp`** is simple enough: it takes a key and a value and returns a function which takes an object, returning a new object with all its properties and the new key/value.

**`nestedMap`** recursively maps a function over a `node: {..., children: [more nodes]}` structure.  The transformation function supplied to it is called first (recursively) on the children of each node and then on the node itself.